# Is it possible to find and compare lengths of multiple lines in the same print statement?

Tags: python-3.x

Im currently working on a textbased charectersheet for rpg's, and so far it's going pretty well. The thing is that, while my stuff works well, I also want it to look good, or at least a bit better than plain text.

Among other things i came up with an idea to put the menues in "boxes", so it was easy to differenciate them from all the other stuf that had been printed. Something like this:

```
¤===========================¤
|Do you understand?         |
|1. Yes                     |
|2. No                      |
|3. Your question is stupid |
¤===========================¤
```

The way i have formulated my menus so far is like this:

```
print("please pick an option:\n"
                  "1. option 1\n"
                  "2. option 2\n")
choice = input()
            if choice == "1":
                    print("Option 1")
            elif choice == "2":
                    print("Option 2")
```

To create this funtion i would have to know how long the longest line in the menu is, so i can make the box the correct size. I know that there are other ways to do this (like doing it manually), but this way i would actually learn somthing new, and it would just be a lot easier for me.

TL;DR:
Is there a way to find the number of characters between each set of \n in a single print statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using a font with all characters equally wide (and no special characters that are wider, such as ★) and you have all the elements (lines) in the menu as strings in a list (I'll call it menuitems for now), you can do the following:

```
maximum_length = max({len(s) for s in menuitems})
```

(Replace the curly brackets {} with square brackets [] if you have mutable elements in your list)

I'm not quite sure what you meant with this question: "Is there a way to find the number of characters between each set of \n in a single print statement?" but if you mean the number of characters in each line of a string (I'll call the string mystring for now):

```
mystring_linelengths = [len(line) for line in mystring.splitlines()]
for i in mystring_linelengths:
    print(i)
```

I hope this helps.